# Apexcharts - donut - change the percentage labels on the donut to the legend

Tags: label, legend, apexcharts, donut-chart

I am looking to create a donut chart where instead of the pieces of the pie showing the percentage of the total, i'd like it to highlight the label/legend for each element?

I have tried using the formatter function e.g.

```
  formatter: function(value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
    return w.config.series[seriesIndex].name + ":  " + value.toFixed(0)+ " %"
  },
```

But this generates labels on each of the donut segments - undefined: 26 %

Would appreciate any thoughts on how to do this.

Many thanks,

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

For donut charts, the labels are stored separately from the data value (i.e. `series`).

When creating the chart you'll pass these values:

```
options = {
    series: [44, 55, 13, 33],
    labels: ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']
}
```

Or if using React/Vue:

```
series: [44, 55, 13, 33],
chartOptions: {
    labels: ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']
}
```

(Both examples from the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/pie-donut/), with slight modification.)

This means that to access the labels in the formatter function, we need to reference `labels` instead of `series`. We can also drop the `.name`.

```
  formatter: function(value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
    return w.config.labels[seriesIndex] + ":  " + value.toFixed(0)+ " %"
  },
```